# How to make a JButton with Windows look have a background color and have the click input?

Tags: java, windows, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel

I just implemented the Windows look and feel in my Java application, but all the buttons lost the background color. After some research, I found out that I had to call the method "buttonName.setContentAreaFilled(false);" followed by "buttonName.setBackground(Color.blue);". That worked as expected, until I realized that the buttons lost the input click.

```
package f.h.projects;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//import control.Control;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
//import negocios.Usuario;

public class FHProjects extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JLabel lCanvas, lLogo, lUsername, lPassword;
    private JTextField jUsername, jPassword;
    private JButton btnLogin;
    private BufferedImage img = null;
    //private ProjectsMenu proye;
    //private Control ctrl;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new FHProjects().setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public FHProjects() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FHProjects.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FHProjects.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FHProjects.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //ctrl = new Control();
/**
//        try {
/**
            setContentPane(lCanvas = new JLabel());
            add(lLogo = new JLabel());
            lLogo.setBounds(250, 50, 200, 200);
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/src/mainLogo.png"));
            Image dimg1 = img.getScaledInstance(lLogo.getWidth(), lLogo.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            ImageIcon imageIcon1 = new ImageIcon(dimg1);
            lLogo.setIcon(imageIcon1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
*/
        lCanvas.setOpaque(true);
        lCanvas.setBackground(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        lCanvas.add(lUsername = new JLabel());
        lCanvas.add(lPassword = new JLabel());
        lCanvas.add(jUsername = new JTextField());
        lCanvas.add(jPassword = new JPasswordField());
        lCanvas.add(btnLogin = new JButton());

        lUsername.setText("User: ");
        lPassword.setText("Password: ");
        btnLogin.setText("Login");
        btnLogin.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnLogin.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnLogin.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnLogin.setOpaque(true);

        lUsername.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 20));
        lPassword.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 20));
        btnLogin.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 15));
        btnLogin.setBackground(java.awt.Color.red);
        btnLogin.setForeground(java.awt.Color.black);
        btnLogin.setBorderPainted(false);

        lUsername.setBounds(200, 280, 100, 30);
        lUsername.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lPassword.setBounds(153, 330, 147, 30);
        lPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jUsername.setBounds(350, 280, 200, 30);
        jPassword.setBounds(350, 330, 200, 30);
        btnLogin.setBounds(300, 400, 100, 30);
        btnLogin.addActionListener(this);

        jUsername.setText("developer");
        jUsername.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    login();
                }
            }
        });
        jPassword.setText("123");
        jPassword.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    login();
                }
            }
        });

        setTitle("F&H Projects");

        setSize(700, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/src/mainLogo.png"));
    }

    public void login() {
        boolean accedio = false;
        /**if (ctrl.login(jUsername.getText(), jPassword.getText()) != null) {
            Usuario user = ctrl.login(jUsername.getText(), jPassword.getText());
            setVisible(false);
            proye = new ProjectsMenu(this, true, user, ctrl);
            accedio = true;

        } else if (accedio == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Username or password is incorrect!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
*/
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton obj = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if (obj == btnLogin) {
            login();
        }
    }
}
```

The buttons work as expected, but it bugs me not to have that input click. If I document the method "buttonName.setContentAreaFilled(false);" or set the parameter to true, the input click comes back but I loose the background color.

Is there a way to have the background color and the input click at the same time in a JButton?

Comment: I forgot to mention that those methods were declared in this class:
public class FHProjects extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {...}

Comment: Add full code. we are not here to put unnecessary exercise to declare variables and import packages.

Comment: Sorry. Just updated the code!

Comment: following code throwing errors. still not able to run your code.
(1) import control.Control; 
(2)  import negocios.Usuario;
(3)  ProjectsMenu

Comment: Done. I documented all the logic of the frame. Anyway, I'm only interested in the click input from the button. It's just an esthetic bug, but considering that going further in the app are 100+ buttons, the visual input of the curson on the buttons it's kinda needed.